# Magento 2: Data migration error

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

I have checked fronted after migration from 1.9.2.1 to 2.1.6 but getting following error on frontend.

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.catalog/category' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW INDEX FROM `catalog/category`
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.catalog/category' doesn't exist
```

I used Magento 2 default migration tool.

Comment: Error on CLI or on site? and you need add table name to ignore mismatch tables. Comment here and i try to solve this.

Comment: In website. And I have already ignored tables and fields.

Comment: did you see migration completed message? i need to see the CLI response. and also tell me if you to migrate all data or some specific data ( ie customer)?

Comment: I migrated all data.

Comment: did you see migration completed success message?

Comment: I got  *[Migration\Exception] Integrity Check failed* error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59802/discussion-between-kishan-patadia-and-jai).